# Is it possible to have a layout for YUI3 App Framwork container?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I am developing my client-side app with YUI3's APP Framework. I am having the following problem: I want to be able to have a few views (let's call them widgets) that are going to stay in the same place on page but under App's container Node, so that events can be registered within App's logic. For example I want a left menu which will have dynamic content (user's navigation panel).

This can be done by creating the menu as a subview, but navigating to another page will result in a page transition and thus, the menu will be included in page transition. I want this subview to be a shared view within many other pages(where page is formed from multiple subviews) but excluded from app's navigation behavior and rendered only once(and updated via custom events).

Does anyone with more experience using YUI App Framework knows hot can I tackle this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. After a closer look on YUI's APP Framework API I found that there are 2 separate properties: container and viewContainer. The former is the node in which the app will reside and the later one is used for dynamically changing the active view on the page. Having this 2 separate properties you have the power to add watever content you want in App besides the pages (which are going to change based on events && routes).

So to conclude you can have a div element which is going to be app's container. Within this element you can write whatever html you want. You can also have another View class here which is going to change based on events(and YUI's custom events are very powerfull). And besides all this "static" html you must have another div(or of course, another html element) which is going to be the active view's container(that'll change based on events or in majority of cases, based on page's URL).